# Pandas merge doesn't retain as many rows as I would think

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

Consider the following two data frames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'bar'], 'b': [1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'baz'], 'c': [3, 4]})
```

Running

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='a')
```

Yields

```
     a  b  c
0  foo  1  3
```

But why not the following?

```
     a  b  c
0  foo  1  3
1  bar  2  -
1  baz  -  4
```

What do I need to tell python to get it to output both rows?

Answer (score 1):

A pandas merge does by default an inner join, if you are familiar with database joins. That means it only returns the rows that have a matching entry in both the left and right dataframe. For you, that is just 'foo'.

You can change that by setting the `how` argument. If you want all rows from both left, and right set it to `outer`, if you want to keep all from the left frame set it to `left`and if you want to keep all from the right frame set it to `right`.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.merge(df1, df2, on='a', how='outer')` will join on matching keys with all non matching keys returned as a new row will `NaN` filling in the blanks.

try [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) for an overview of different types of SQL style joins which `merge` uses as basis.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your code ran without specifying the "how = ". Without specifying "how = left", by default pandas merge assumes "how = inner" which returns only the common rows in both dataframes. In your case, try specifying "how = left" to return everything on df1. So your code should look like this

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='a', how ='left')
```